# Hadoop data visualization

Tags: hadoop

I am a new hadoop developer and I have been able to install and run hadoop services in a single-node cluster. The problem comes during data visualization. What purpose does MapReduce jar file play when I need to use a data visualization tool like Tableau. I have a structured data source in which I need to add a layer of logic so that the data could make sense during visualization. Do I need to write MapReduce programs if I am going to visualize with other tools? Please shed some light on how I could go about on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This probably depends on what distribution of Hadoop you are using and which tools are present. It also depends on the actual data preparation task.

If you don't want to actually write map-reduce or spark code yourself you could try SQL-like queries using **Hive** (which translates to map-reduce) or the even faster **Impala**. Using SQL you can create tabular data (hive tables) which can easily be consumed. Tableau has connectors for both of them that automatically translate your tableau configurations/requests to Hive/Impala. I would recommend connecting with Impala because of its speed.
If you need to do work that requires more programming or where SQL just isn't enough you could try **Pig**. Pig is a high level scripting language that compiles to map-reduce code. You can try all of the above in their respective editor in Hue or from CLI.

If you feel like all of the above still don't fit your use case I would suggest writing **map-reduce** or **spark** code. Spark does not need to be written in Java only and has the advantage of being generally faster.

Most tools can integrate with hive tables meaning you don't need to rewrite code. If a tool does not provide this you can make CSV extracts from the hive tables or you can keep the tables stored as CSV/TSV. You can then import these files in your visualization tool.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer already touches on this but is a bit broad, so I decided to focus on the key part:

**Typical steps for data visualisation**

1. Do the complex calculations using any hadoop tool that you like
2. Offer the output in a (hive) table
3. Pull the data into the memory of the visualisation tool (e.g. Tableau), for instance using JDBC

If the data is too big to be pulled into memory, you could pull it into a normal SQL database instead and work on that directly from your visualisation tool. (If you work directly on hive, you will go crazy as the simplest queries take 30+ seconds.)

---

In case it is not possible/desirable to connect your visualisation tool for some reason, the workaround would be to dump output files, for instance as CSV, and then load these into the visualisation tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some end to end solutions for data visualization.

For example like [**Metatron Discovery**](https://metatron.app), it uses [druid](http://druid.io) as their OLAP engine. So you just link your hadoop with Druid and then you can manage and visualize your hadoop data accordingly. This is an [open source](http://github.com/metatron-app/metatron-discovery) so that you also can see the code inside it.